# Report Viewer - app.config desconfigurado

Tags: c#, mysql, reportviewer

Eu não estou conseguindo realizar uma conexão Report Viewer com o Mysql, não aparece na lista "Escolher Fonte de Dados". Eu acredito que o problema seja no "app.config" que está desconfigurado alguém poderia me passar o código inteiro do "app.config" para o Mysql Conector/NET 6.9.12 Visual Studio Community 2017

O código do meu app.config inteiro é:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Gold_Business.Properties.Settings.bgmysqlConnectionString"
            connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;database=bgmysql"
            providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Ao substituir o código abaixo no código acima o problema persiste pois as outras partes do código não estão corretas apresentando o erro abaixo do código. Como deveria ficar o "app.config" inteiro para o para o Mysql Conector/NET 6.9.12?

```
<connectionStrings>  
    <add name="myDatabaseConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;user=root;database=mydatabase;port=3306;password=mypassword;" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Olá, segue exemplo de connectionString pelo app.config para Mysql.

```
<connectionStrings>  
    <add name="myDatabaseConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;user=root;database=mydatabase;port=3306;password=mypassword;" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: O problema persiste pois está faltando a codificação completa do app.config para o para o Mysql Conector/NET 6.9.12.